# How to use complex document text as the input variable in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this vue:

```
<script>
var starting_point =  '{{ form.content.data }}';
vm = new Vue({
  el: '#editor',
  data: {
    input: starting_point
  },
  computed: {
    compiledMarkdown: function () {
        console.log(marked(this.input,{sanitize:true}));
      return marked(this.input, { sanitize: true });
    }
  },
  methods: {
    update: _.debounce(function (e) {
      this.input = e.target.value
    }, 300)
  }
});
```

This is from the basic example in vue: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/

It works fine for short sentences. However, once my blog posts - given with `{{ form.content.data }}` start getting longer and having custom stuff like emojis and line breaks, the javascript variable starts breaking. For instance I see stuff like this:

```
var starting_point =  '# fourthwhat is this? 
;o
how bout dat. ';
```

and it says: `2:40 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` at the end of the ? I think because theres a line break or something.

So I think I need to stringify this whole thing or somehow make it safe to use as the javascript variable. Is there a good way to do this so that vue can understand it?

Comment: [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) can be multi-line and will avoid most problems.

Comment: Is this working properly? https://jsfiddle.net/wo9ahaav/1/

Comment: You could also just put the text in the textarea and [initialize your variable from there](https://jsfiddle.net/wo9ahaav/2/).

Comment: yep template strings seem to work, and test that fiddle works. @BertEvans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it breaks is because you are not escaping the new line character.
i.e., instead of this:

```
var starting_point =  '# fourthwhat is this? 
;o
how bout dat. ';
```

Your code should look like this:

```
var starting_point =  '# fourthwhat is this? \
;o \
how bout dat. ';
```

So, if you're getting the markdown string from an external, dynamic source, you'll have to add the `\` character before each line break.

**EDIT**: alternatively, you could just use the backtick operator (`):

```
var starting_point =  `# fourthwhat is this? 
;o
how bout dat. `;
```